# Proving CLDM is in QMA, In particular why is it possible to assume that the given input is a product of copies in the soundness section?

Tags: density-matrix, complexity-theory, qma

I'm wondering about a specific proof for Consistency of Local Density Matrices (CLDM) $ \in $ QMA appearing in "QMA-hardness of Consistency of Local Density Matrices with Applications to Quantum Zero-Knowledge". Arxiv link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.07782.pdf#page=18&zoom=100,96,265.

The link should point directly to Lemma 3.3 on page 18.

In the soundness section, The authors assume that the candidate given by the prover is a product state. As far as I know, in the QMA settings, such an assumption can't be made. What do I miss? Does the concentration argument still work even when the given states are entangled? Thanks.

Comment: Consider spelling out CLDM; and please be more specific about which part of the paper exactly you are referring to.